# Vuetify Form with a template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I would like to build a form with datas from a JSON.

The JSON look like this and stored in a settings[] object from an axios request:

```
[ {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "CAR_NETWORK",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "SALES_FCT_SKU_MAX",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "name" : "SALES_FCT_SKU_MIN",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 5,
  "name" : "NB_PCB",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 6,
  "name" : "DESCENTR_SC1_SC2",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 7,
  "name" : "DESCENTR_SC3_SC4",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 8,
  "name" : "DVS_CAR",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 9,
  "name" : "DVS_MAG",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 10,
  "name" : "VMCAR_PCB",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 11,
  "name" : "VMCAR_PAL",
  "value" : 1.00
}, {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "COEFF_SEASON_MAX",
  "value" : 1.00
} ]
```

and I would like to build a v-template with textfields like this :

```
<v-text-field v-model="value" label="name"></v-text-field>
```

Do someone have an idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Im not quite sure that you will need only textfields for this scenario in case you want the user to select any of these. Probable checkboxes or radio buttons would be better for your case.

Comment: No, that's not a checkboxes, I would like to have multiple text-fields where I can modify the values after.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably pass your name through a dictionary to convert it into a readable string

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        JSON: [ {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "CAR_NETWORK",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "SALES_FCT_SKU_MAX",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 4,
            "name" : "SALES_FCT_SKU_MIN",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "NB_PCB",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 6,
            "name" : "DESCENTR_SC1_SC2",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 7,
            "name" : "DESCENTR_SC3_SC4",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 8,
            "name" : "DVS_CAR",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 9,
            "name" : "DVS_MAG",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 10,
            "name" : "VMCAR_PCB",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 11,
            "name" : "VMCAR_PAL",
            "value" : 1.00
          }, {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "COEFF_SEASON_MAX",
            "value" : 1.00
          } ]
      })
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" v-for="field in JSON" :key="field.id">
              <v-text-field v-model="field.value" :label="field.name"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>
```